# What is the moment when all oscillators aligned to make a jump called?

Tags: fourier-series, terminology, oscillator, resonance

Say we have a square wave and its Fourier series. When the wave doesn't jump, its oscillators aren't aligned:

[image]

But if they are aligned, the wave will jump:

[image]

What is this moment called? They might not be necessary in the same angle, and I don't think "resonating together" is correct, since they have different frequencies. What is it called when all oscillators aligned to make a jump?

<sup>Meta discussion: [Why are questions asking for terms off-topic?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1574/31713)</sup>

Comment: Coincidence of zero crossings and same sign of derivation?

Comment: too long...........

Comment: Try searching on "gibbs phenomenon". Those are the little squiggles you see on the flat part of your square wave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Phasor Alignment* : The individual frequency component phasors of the square wave are aligning, but I don't think this is a well-defined (or previously-defined) term.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word/phrase you are looking for is "discontinuity" / "discontinuity in the source signal".  Although a jump is always a discontinuity, a discontinuity is not always a jump.  When it isn't a jump, it is known as a pluggable discontinuity, i.e. you can define a value to plug a hole.  The sinc function at zero is an example of this.  So to be more specific you would say "an unpluggable discontinuity".

Whether a series of continuous functions could converge to a discontinuous function was a question that led to some very serious, and non-intuitive, math.

As far as I know, there is no word to describe the state of the components at this moment.  The closest word I can think of is a secondary meaning of "concordance" = "agreement".

Hope this helps.

Ced

Comment: I find out that the term is actually [removable discontinuity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html). But yes, I'm looking for a word of the state of the components. If you think there is no word for this, I think this question is better suited in [english.se]

Answer (score 3):

It is the time of maximum *constructive interference* of the derivatives of the harmonics. That's a physics term, but widely known.

Answer (score 0):

One can simply say the oscillators are **in sync**, or *synchronized*. Some other synonyms of the *synchronization* in English are: conjunction co-occurrence, concurrence, coincidence, coexistence, simultaneity, contemporaneity, concomitance, synchronicity, synchrony